# How can I pass a credential parameter to a buildWithParameter API call in Jenkins?

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to pass a Credentials parameter from the [JENKINS Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) to a buildWithParameter API call I want to trigger from PHP, but I couldn't find in the user documention how to format such parameter.

Is there a way to do through the URL, like for example, through the Id of the credentials?

Do I need to create the credentials on the go, or can I use the one I created, provided I authenticate myself?

Do I need instead to go through a Jenkins REST API client to do something like that?

Or is it even possible through RESTful API? If not what are my other options to trigger a build remotely while giving a Credentials parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that one can use the Credentials parameter ID. So for example, if you created a Crendential mydbuser/mydbpass with id mydbuserid you can then trigger a build with

```
http://jenkins.example.com/path/to/job/buildWithParameter?dbUser=mydbuserid
```

Also be aware that for some passwords containing special characters, you might get the following exception:

`Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`